# DebugPackage is a type and can not be used as exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a VB.net application and I have a function with this signature:

```
Public Function DeSerializeAnObject(XmlOfAnObject As String, ObjectType As Type) As [Object]
```

but following call is giving error (at DebugPackage):

```
 Dim obj As ObjectSerializer = New ObjectSerializer
        obj.DeSerializeAnObject("", TypeOf(DebugPackage))
```

> DebugPackage is a type and can not be used as exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the right keyword, you should use [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/tay4kywk.aspx) instead of [TypeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx):

```
Dim obj As New ObjectSerializer
obj.DeSerializeAnObject("", GetType(DebugPackage))
```

Differences between `GetType` and `TypeOf` functions:

```
Dim obj As String = ""

' TypeOf operator checks if an Object belongs to a Type. 
' It cannot be used without the "Is SomeType" part
Dim isString As Boolean = TypeOf obj is String

' GetType operator returns Type information for a specified Type
Dim type As Type = GetType(String)

' Also, objects have a GetType method to retrieve it's Type
type = obj.GetType()
```